# xlw: how to use new typedef to get std::string from Excel cells (and possibly populate a std::map)

Tags: c++, templates, xlw

**Introduction**

I am referring to [**xlw**](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/), the Excel C API wrapper by Mark Joshi and others.

Before starting with my example, my trials and my question, a couple of words about how to reproduce these codes: once you've downloaded and installed `xlw` from its website, you should find a folder named `XLL_Project`, whose contents is a Visual Studio solution ("**Template.sln**") if this IDE/platform has been selected during installation; this solution is made of a `cppinterface.h`, that is, an header file which defines what functions should be present in your final .xll, and a `source.cpp`, which specifies how said functions should behave.

**Code**

Let an interface function like the following one is in `cppinterface.h` and its behavior is in `source.cpp`:

```
// ===== cppinterface.h =====

std::string // Asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by different people. Analyzes the data and output which person ate the most pancakes
    PancakeGlutton(const MyArray& people, // Range of people
                   const MyArray& pancakeNumber // Range of pancakes eaten by each person
                  );
```

---

```
// ===== source.pp =====

std::string PancakeGlutton(const MyArray& people, const MyArray& pancakeNumber)
{
    if (people.size() != pancakeNumber.size())
        throw("Error: arrays must have the same dimension!");
    std::map< std::string, int > myMap;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
    {
        myMap.insert(std::pair< std::string, int >(people[i], pancakeNumber[i]));
    }
    return "x"; // Of course this a strange output just for the sake of this example
}
```

As you can see, there's an attempt to populate a `std::map< std::string, int >` using the `xlw` class `MyArray`: in the Excel spreadsheet `people` could be a range of strings, hence C++ code should see something like a `std::vector< std::string >` and thus it should use it to populate `myMap` with proper `std::pair< std::string, int >`.

However, this doesn't build.

Main issue is that `MyArray` is a `typedef` defined in `mycontainers.h`:

```
// ===== mycontainers.h =====
// Line 68
// ...
   typedef std::vector<double> MyArray;
```

Therefore, no way it can be translated into a container able to manage strings: just doubles. Even though in [**his book**](http://books.google.it/books?hl=it&lr=&id=ocW3HsLs4zUC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=c%2B%2B%20derivatives%20pricing%20and%20design%20patterns%20joshi&ots=rcuz85uc1K&sig=qGtnfabmynQYj40Zd-JNiodraqc#v=onepage&q=c%2B%2B%20derivatives%20pricing%20and%20design%20patterns%20joshi&f=false)'s chapter related to `xlw` Joshi says...

> [...] The class `MyArray` is also defined via a `typedef` in `MyContainers.h`. The default is to `typedef` to `std::vector`. It must have `.size()`, a constructor taking the size, and `operator[]` defined.

...it is not sufficient to add

```
typedef std::vector< std::string > MyStrArray;
```

neither to `mycontainers.h` nor to any header file of my project.

**Questions**

1. How may I populate that `std::map< std::string, int>` by reading a
   range of strings from Excel?
2. How may I define new containers via
   `typedef` according to my desired types/classes in order to manage
   all possible inputs from Excel?

Comment: Is mycontainers.h part of the sample template?  It looks like it is not part of the xlw documentation.  I  would think you could just change the typedef.

Comment: It's an external dependency. I've tried to amend the code by adding that definition but it doesn't build anyway. I guess something else must be done elsewhere, but I can't figure out where or how.

Comment: Have you tried with `typedef std::vector< std::wstring > MyStrArray;`? Excel strings shoud be unicode.

Answer (score 2):

The MyArray class is only intended to represent arrays of doubles. The typedef is so you can use your favourite such class.

The CellMatrix class allows you to input data of any type. You simply test each element of the CellMatrix for its type and then do what you want with it.